# How std::advance iterator type is deduced?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, time-complexity

Please take a look at the [`std::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) function.
According to cppreference the complexity is:

> Linear.
>   However, if InputIt additionally meets the requirements of RandomAccessIterator, complexity is constant.

So if I pass an iterator and an integer, how does the program deduce what iterator it is and how it is implemented? So are there 2 overloads for the function or what?

Comment: [`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits), see `iterator_category`.

Comment: For these kinds of queries it's always worth cracking open the source code of the standard library and trying to understand it by reading the code. On linux it can normally be found under `/usr/include/c++/<version>`.

Comment: and on windods, @PaulRooney?

Comment: not sure sorry and I dont have windows handy. Wouldn't be too hard to search for it though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> how program deduce what iterator it and how it is implemented?

It uses `std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category` to determine iterator category and then does *tag dispatching*.

[`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) is specialised for raw pointers. Raw pointers are random-access iterators.

E.g.:

```
template<class I>
void doadvance(I& i, size_t n, std::random_access_iterator_tag) {
    i += n;
}

template<class I, class Tag>
void doadvance(I& i, size_t n, Tag) {
    while(n--)
        ++i;
}

template<class I>
void advance(I& i, size_t n) {
    using Tag = typename std::iterator_traits<I>::iterator_category;
    doadvance(i, n, Tag{});
}
```

In C++17 instead of *tag dispatching* it can use `if constexpr`, but that would make the standard library not backward compatible. This is why it has to keep using *tag dispatching*.

IMO, [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) has a better interface than `std::advance` because it returns the iterator, so that the invocation does not have to occupy its own line of code.

Comment: @EduardRostomyan `std::iterator_traits` is specialized for raw pointers. Raw pointers are random-access iterators.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: There's no requirement in the standard for it to use tag dispatching like this. C++17 implementations which still use it do so by choice. Now yes, the `if constexpr` expression has to be based on the random access tag, but it doesn't have to delegate the call through it.

Comment: @NicolBolas I did not say the standard requires using tag dispatching. And I did not say that `if constexpr` has to delegate. Quite to the contrary, `if constexpr` removes the need to do tag dispatching.

Answer (score 6):

> how program deduce what iterator it is

[`std::iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) is used, i.e. `std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category` will be checked, and if it's [`std::random_access_iterator_tag`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags), means it's a RandomAccessIterator.

BTW: `std::iterator_traits` is specialized for raw pointers; they're always RandomAccessIterator.

> So are there 2 overloads for the function or what?

There're no more overloads of `std::advance`, the implementation usually implements several helper function overloads, which are called according to the iterator_category in `std::advance`.

Comment: @Slava Answer revised.